# ElasticSearch: bad relevance order

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack

This is the mapping of my index:

```
{
  "itens" : {
    "mappings" : {
      "properties" : {
        "card_id" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          }
        },
        "name" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

When I run this search:

```
GET itens/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "match": {
            "name": {
              "query": "camisa",
              "_name": "camisa"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "name": {
              "query": "flamengo",
              "_name": "flamengo"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "name": {
              "query": "edição",
              "_name": "edição"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "name": {
              "query": "torcedor",
              "_name": "torcedor"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

I get the following results:

```
{
  "took" : 2,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 8,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : 3.2621913,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "itens",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "lDJ-5WwBSsI9bleNzslS",
        "_score" : 3.2621913,
        "_source" : {
          "card_id" : "centauro",
          "name" : "Bola Nike Edição Flamengo"
        },
        "matched_queries" : [
          "edição",
          "flamengo"
        ]
      },
      {
        "_index" : "itens",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "lzKB5WwBSsI9bleNeMnt",
        "_score" : 3.0658486,
        "_source" : {
          "card_id" : "centauro",
          "name" : "Camisa do Flamengo Vermelha Edição 100 Anos"
        },
        "matched_queries" : [
          "camisa",
          "edição",
          "flamengo"
        ]
      },
      {
        "_index" : "itens",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "yV4q0WwB-vWXMqGoqMdJ",
        "_score" : 2.7421699,
        "_source" : {
          "card_id" : "centauro",
          "name" : "Camisa Flamengo 2019 Masculina Modelo Torcedor"
        },
        "matched_queries" : [
          "camisa",
          "torcedor",
          "flamengo"
        ]
      },
      ...and some others...
```

My question is: why the second and third results are sorted lower (have lower score) than the first result and how can I fix that?

Both second and third results have 3 matched queries while the first result has only 2. This is a clearly bad relevance order, as the second and third results have much more relevance to my search than the first one.

I found [this ElasticSearch doc about relevancies that looks wrong](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/consistent-scoring.html#_relevancy_looks_wrong) and I tried to search with `_search?search_type=dfs_query_then_fetch`, but it gets me the same results.

**EDIT**:

I created a new index for tests with the same mapping and I inserted these 3 documents I've talked about: `Bola Nike Edição Flamengo`, `Camisa do Flamengo Vermelha Edição 100 Anos` and `Camisa Flamengo 2019 Masculina Modelo Torcedor`.

I ran the same query and the result was right, as I expected. So I thought maybe the problem only occurs when I have other documents besides these 3. So I inserted other documents I have in my original index and "bang!", the problem is there again.

I only had to insert 2 other documents to repeat the problem: `Camisa Palmeiras 2019 Masculina Modelo Torcedor` and `Camisa Internacional 2019 Masculina Modelo Torcedor`.

My search result was this:

```
{
  "took" : 2,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 5,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : 1.6201596,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "teste",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "nzKM8mwBSsI9bleNrsmM",
        "_score" : 1.6201596,
        "_source" : {
          "card_id" : "some place",
          "name" : "Bola Nike Edição Flamengo"
        },
        "matched_queries" : [
          "edição",
          "flamengo"
        ]
      },
      {
        "_index" : "teste",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "gCaO8mwBepmixz6CaMCt",
        "_score" : 1.5693209,
        "_source" : {
          "card_id" : "some place",
          "name" : "Camisa do Flamengo Vermelha Edição 100 Anos"
        },
        "matched_queries" : [
          "camisa",
          "edição",
          "flamengo"
        ]
      },
      {
        "_index" : "teste",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "fyaN8mwBepmixz6CQcBc",
        "_score" : 1.3466781,
        "_source" : {
          "card_id" : "some place",
          "name" : "Camisa Flamengo 2019 Masculina Modelo Torcedor"
        },
        "matched_queries" : [
          "camisa",
          "torcedor",
          "flamengo"
        ]
      },
      {
        "_index" : "teste",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "gSaP8mwBepmixz6CbsDW",
        "_score" : 0.8151792,
        "_source" : {
          "card_id" : "some place",
          "name" : "Camisa Palmeiras 2019 Masculina Modelo Torcedor"
        },
        "matched_queries" : [
          "camisa",
          "torcedor"
        ]
      },
      {
        "_index" : "teste",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "giaP8mwBepmixz6C4MCL",
        "_score" : 0.8151792,
        "_source" : {
          "card_id" : "some place",
          "name" : "Camisa Internacional 2019 Masculina Modelo Torcedor"
        },
        "matched_queries" : [
          "camisa",
          "torcedor"
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I ran the search with `?explain=true` and the outcome was too long to paste here, but I will paste the explanation of the first 2 documents in the result:

```
{
        "_shard" : "[teste][0]",
        "_node" : "xnRySBw_T7Kjsl4wAa_2yg",
        "_index" : "teste",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "nzKM8mwBSsI9bleNrsmM",
        "_score" : 1.6201596,
        "_source" : {
          "card_id" : "some place",
          "name" : "Bola Nike Edição Flamengo"
        },
        "matched_queries" : [
          "edição",
          "flamengo"
        ],
        "_explanation" : {
          "value" : 1.6201596,
          "description" : "sum of:",
          "details" : [
            {
              "value" : 0.6173784,
              "description" : "weight(name:flamengo in 0) [PerFieldSimilarity], result of:",
              "details" : [
                {
                  "value" : 0.6173784,
                  "description" : "score(freq=1.0), product of:",
                  "details" : [
                    {
                      "value" : 2.2,
                      "description" : "boost",
                      "details" : [ ]
                    },
                    {
                      "value" : 0.5389965,
                      "description" : "idf, computed as log(1 + (N - n + 0.5) / (n + 0.5)) from:",
                      "details" : [
                        {
                          "value" : 3,
                          "description" : "n, number of documents containing term",
                          "details" : [ ]
                        },
                        {
                          "value" : 5,
                          "description" : "N, total number of documents with field",
                          "details" : [ ]
                        }
                      ]
                    },
                    {
                      "value" : 0.52064633,
                      "description" : "tf, computed as freq / (freq + k1 * (1 - b + b * dl / avgdl)) from:",
                      "details" : [
                        {
                          "value" : 1.0,
                          "description" : "freq, occurrences of term within document",
                          "details" : [ ]
                        },
                        {
                          "value" : 1.2,
                          "description" : "k1, term saturation parameter",
                          "details" : [ ]
                        },
                        {
                          "value" : 0.75,
                          "description" : "b, length normalization parameter",
                          "details" : [ ]
                        },
                        {
                          "value" : 4.0,
                          "description" : "dl, length of field",
                          "details" : [ ]
                        },
                        {
                          "value" : 5.8,
                          "description" : "avgdl, average length of field",
                          "details" : [ ]
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  ]
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "value" : 1.0027812,
              "description" : "weight(name:edição in 0) [PerFieldSimilarity], result of:",
              "details" : [
                {
                  "value" : 1.0027812,
                  "description" : "score(freq=1.0), product of:",
                  "details" : [
                    {
                      "value" : 2.2,
                      "description" : "boost",
                      "details" : [ ]
                    },
                    {
                      "value" : 0.87546873,
                      "description" : "idf, computed as log(1 + (N - n + 0.5) / (n + 0.5)) from:",
                      "details" : [
                        {
                          "value" : 2,
                          "description" : "n, number of documents containing term",
                          "details" : [ ]
                        },
                        {
                          "value" : 5,
                          "description" : "N, total number of documents with field",
                          "details" : [ ]
                        }
                      ]
                    },
                    {
                      "value" : 0.52064633,
                      "description" : "tf, computed as freq / (freq + k1 * (1 - b + b * dl / avgdl)) from:",
                      "details" : [
                        {
                          "value" : 1.0,
                          "description" : "freq, occurrences of term within document",
                          "details" : [ ]
                        },
                        {
                          "value" : 1.2,
                          "description" : "k1, term saturation parameter",
                          "details" : [ ]
                        },
                        {
                          "value" : 0.75,
                          "description" : "b, length normalization parameter",
                          "details" : [ ]
                        },
                        {
                          "value" : 4.0,
                          "description" : "dl, length of field",
                          "details" : [ ]
                        },
                        {
                          "value" : 5.8,
                          "description" : "avgdl, average length of field",
                          "details" : [ ]
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "_shard" : "[teste][0]",
        "_node" : "xnRySBw_T7Kjsl4wAa_2yg",
        "_index" : "teste",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "gCaO8mwBepmixz6CaMCt",
        "_score" : 1.5693209,
        "_source" : {
          "card_id" : "some place",
          "name" : "Camisa do Flamengo Vermelha Edição 100 Anos"
        },
        "matched_queries" : [
          "camisa",
          "edição",
          "flamengo"
        ],
        "_explanation" : {
          "value" : 1.5693209,
          "description" : "sum of:",
          "details" : [
            {
              "value" : 0.26523292,
              "description" : "weight(name:camisa in 1) [PerFieldSimilarity], result of:",
              "details" : [
                {
                  "value" : 0.26523292,
                  "description" : "score(freq=1.0), product of:",
                  "details" : [
                    {
                      "value" : 2.2,
                      "description" : "boost",
                      "details" : [ ]
                    },
                    {
                      "value" : 0.2876821,
                      "description" : "idf, computed as log(1 + (N - n + 0.5) / (n + 0.5)) from:",
                      "details" : [
                        {
                          "value" : 4,
                          "description" : "n, number of documents containing term",
                          "details" : [ ]
                        },
                        {
                          "value" : 5,
                          "description" : "N, total number of documents with field",
                          "details" : [ ]
                        }
                      ]
                    },
                    {
                      "value" : 0.41907516,
                      "description" : "tf, computed as freq / (freq + k1 * (1 - b + b * dl / avgdl)) from:",
                      "details" : [
                        {
                          "value" : 1.0,
                          "description" : "freq, occurrences of term within document",
                          "details" : [ ]
                        },
                        {
                          "value" : 1.2,
                          "description" : "k1, term saturation parameter",
                          "details" : [ ]
                        },
                        {
                          "value" : 0.75,
                          "description" : "b, length normalization parameter",
                          "details" : [ ]
                        },
                        {
                          "value" : 7.0,
                          "description" : "dl, length of field",
                          "details" : [ ]
                        },
                        {
                          "value" : 5.8,
                          "description" : "avgdl, average length of field",
                          "details" : [ ]
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  ]
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "value" : 0.4969361,
              "description" : "weight(name:flamengo in 1) [PerFieldSimilarity], result of:",
              "details" : [
                {
                  "value" : 0.4969361,
                  "description" : "score(freq=1.0), product of:",
                  "details" : [
                    {
                      "value" : 2.2,
                      "description" : "boost",
                      "details" : [ ]
                    },
                    {
                      "value" : 0.5389965,
                      "description" : "idf, computed as log(1 + (N - n + 0.5) / (n + 0.5)) from:",
                      "details" : [
                        {
                          "value" : 3,
                          "description" : "n, number of documents containing term",
                          "details" : [ ]
                        },
                        {
                          "value" : 5,
                          "description" : "N, total number of documents with field",
                          "details" : [ ]
                        }
                      ]
                    },
                    {
                      "value" : 0.41907516,
                      "description" : "tf, computed as freq / (freq + k1 * (1 - b + b * dl / avgdl)) from:",
                      "details" : [
                        {
                          "value" : 1.0,
                          "description" : "freq, occurrences of term within document",
                          "details" : [ ]
                        },
                        {
                          "value" : 1.2,
                          "description" : "k1, term saturation parameter",
                          "details" : [ ]
                        },
                        {
                          "value" : 0.75,
                          "description" : "b, length normalization parameter",
                          "details" : [ ]
                        },
                        {
                          "value" : 7.0,
                          "description" : "dl, length of field",
                          "details" : [ ]
                        },
                        {
                          "value" : 5.8,
                          "description" : "avgdl, average length of field",
                          "details" : [ ]
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  ]
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "value" : 0.80715185,
              "description" : "weight(name:edição in 1) [PerFieldSimilarity], result of:",
              "details" : [
                {
                  "value" : 0.80715185,
                  "description" : "score(freq=1.0), product of:",
                  "details" : [
                    {
                      "value" : 2.2,
                      "description" : "boost",
                      "details" : [ ]
                    },
                    {
                      "value" : 0.87546873,
                      "description" : "idf, computed as log(1 + (N - n + 0.5) / (n + 0.5)) from:",
                      "details" : [
                        {
                          "value" : 2,
                          "description" : "n, number of documents containing term",
                          "details" : [ ]
                        },
                        {
                          "value" : 5,
                          "description" : "N, total number of documents with field",
                          "details" : [ ]
                        }
                      ]
                    },
                    {
                      "value" : 0.41907516,
                      "description" : "tf, computed as freq / (freq + k1 * (1 - b + b * dl / avgdl)) from:",
                      "details" : [
                        {
                          "value" : 1.0,
                          "description" : "freq, occurrences of term within document",
                          "details" : [ ]
                        },
                        {
                          "value" : 1.2,
                          "description" : "k1, term saturation parameter",
                          "details" : [ ]
                        },
                        {
                          "value" : 0.75,
                          "description" : "b, length normalization parameter",
                          "details" : [ ]
                        },
                        {
                          "value" : 7.0,
                          "description" : "dl, length of field",
                          "details" : [ ]
                        },
                        {
                          "value" : 5.8,
                          "description" : "avgdl, average length of field",
                          "details" : [ ]
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      }
```

I don't know exactly what to look for here. What I know is that the first result should have a lower score than the second one.

Comment: what elastic search version are you using? I couldn't reproduce it in ES 5.1

Comment: I'm using the 14-day trial period. The version of the deployment is v7.3.1.

Answer (score 1):

> I found this ElasticSearch doc about relevancies that looks wrong and
>   I tried to search with `_search?search_type=dfs_query_then_fetch`, but
>   it gets me the same results.

Version 7.0 of Elasticsearch changed the default number of primary shards to 1. So you don't have this problem any more as long as you don't specify a different number explicitly. In your query result you can see that you have the default of only a single shard: `"_shards" : { "total" : 1`.

First, let's create a minimal reproducible example.

Mapping:

```
PUT itens
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "name": {
        "type": "text"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Example documents:

```
PUT itens/_doc/1
{
  "name": "Bola Nike Edição Flamengo"
}
PUT itens/_doc/2
{
  "name": "Camisa do Flamengo Vermelha Edição 100 Anos"
}
PUT itens/_doc/3
{
  "name": "Camisa Flamengo 2019 Masculina Modelo Torcedor"
}
```

I'm using the query you have provided above and get the following results:

```
"hits" : [
  {
    "_index" : "itens",
    "_type" : "_doc",
    "_id" : "3",
    "_score" : 1.5471338,
    "_source" : {
      "name" : "Camisa Flamengo 2019 Masculina Modelo Torcedor"
    },
    "matched_queries" : [
      "camisa",
      "torcedor",
      "flamengo"
    ]
  },
  {
    "_index" : "itens",
    "_type" : "_doc",
    "_id" : "2",
    "_score" : 0.97927666,
    "_source" : {
      "name" : "Camisa do Flamengo Vermelha Edição 100 Anos"
    },
    "matched_queries" : [
      "camisa",
      "edição",
      "flamengo"
    ]
  },
  {
    "_index" : "itens",
    "_type" : "_doc",
    "_id" : "1",
    "_score" : 0.6860854,
    "_source" : {
      "name" : "Bola Nike Edição Flamengo"
    },
    "matched_queries" : [
      "edição",
      "flamengo"
    ]
  }
]
```

So with the minimal example you are getting what you'd expect.

To debug what is happening with your query, add the parameter `?explain=true` to your query so that the full line looks like `GET itens/_search?explain=true`. This will add a lot of output, but should explain much better what is happening there. Please add that to your original question and if the outcome isn't clear add a comment, so we can have another look.

Comment: I edited my post if you could take another look. The problem only occurs when you have more documents indexed. It somehow affects the score calculation in a bad way. I've added the `explanation` you suggested too.